# Flag data in the data explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, flags

I'd love to see if there are trends over time, patterns of improving behaviour after being flagged, consistent reoffenders, most misused types of flag, etc.

I understand the who-said-what-about-who aspect would most likely cause this to be denied, but even anonymised data would be interesting to dig through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this *would* be nice to have, but the data needed to do the analysis isn't available publicly.

The vast majority of the data is deleted content -- either spammy posts that have been flagged into the stone age, or simply flags that have decayed away. None of that is included in the data dump. The only part that *can* be had are the "in progress" spam/offensive flags, which have been flagged very recently relative to when the data dump was produced.

So as I said, doing a trend analysis would be nice to do here, but at this point it's not possible. I wouldn't say it will *never* be possible... though you'll have to argue for deleted content to be available in the data dump, which is a pretty tall order.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting. Is there remit for the data dump to be extended to some rudimentary post information (not body text for example), for reasonably recent flagged posts? A day/week?

Comment: I guess a deleted data is deleted data, thinking about it. Troublesome.

Comment: @Stuart: Well, as I said, some of this data does exist in the dump -- flags that aren't deleted. But the few of those won't really be much help in the analysis you want to do.

Comment: Indeed. As in any analysis, useful conclusions can rarely be drawn from incomplete data. Thanks for looking into it anyway.

Comment: @JonSeigel : it [already exist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257166/242800). Did you also know that link to deleted questions were available in data Dumps?

Answer (score 1):

It’s already available.

Just look at the [PendingFlags table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/242800)

### PendingFlags

- `Id`
- `FlagTypeId` (listed in the `FlagTypes` table)
  13. canned flag for closure
  14. vote to close
  15. vote to reopen
- `PostId`
- `CreationDate`
- `CloseReasonTypeId` (listed in the `CloseReasonTypes` table)
- `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId`, if `CloseReasonTypeId = 102 (off-topic)` (listed in the `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes` table)
- `DuplicateOfQuestionId`, if `CloseReasonTypeId` is 1 or 101 (old duplicate or current duplicate)
- `BelongsOnBaseHostAddress`, for votes to close and migrate

I already used it in some of [my queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193616) when I thought it was good to tool for finding question that should be closed.

Comment: These are only for *pending* flags, and therefore won't give any indication of trends. One sites with a low number of low quality posts, this table is pretty much empty most of the time. So, in essence, this does not answer the question...

Comment: @Werner but at least with sites with large untriaged flags and large usage like stack overflow, this offers helps over time.