# Make Handled flags also availaible

Tags: feature-request, flags, data-explorer

Some months ago *(when Meta was still Meta Stack Overflow)*, I got [the feeling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228615/242800#comment749672_228615) that the time a flag get handled is increasing when the first flagging is trigged on a question older than one month compared to when it happens during the first hour.

Recently [flag expiry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207182/242800) got implemented which according to me means the percentage of handled flags according to the question age drops. But proving so would require writing a query and as the implementation is still new it would be good to consider past handled flags.
For such a query, I would need to access flags which got handled, but currently only PendingFlags with close votes are available on SEDE. The best would be an handled date for each flags.

Since there is already a PendingFlags table, please also make handled flags available with there handled date also available on SEDE so I can output a graph of handled flag percentage over time.

## Update

**This question ask  asks for data on handled fags. [Flag data in the data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84308/242800) ask for accessing flagged data in general whether Pending or not which is considered as [implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257166/242800).**

**Please don’t close it!**

Comment: @hichris123 No Flag data is already available on SEDE. But only for flags which weren’t handled. So [Flag data in the data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84308/242800) already exist. I want something more than the existing PendingFlag table.